# Logn in to one remote machine shows as -bash-4.2$ in terminal while user@host$ on other remote servers? How to fix this?

Tags: unix, terminal

When I'm login in to one remote machine over `ssh` it logs in as `-bash-4.2$` in terminal but on other remote hosts `user@host$`. How to correct this? I accidentally executed `rm -rf *`. 
Looks like I delete some important files from home directory.
**Note: I'm not the admin.**

Comment: What is your OS? Please show the output of `ls -la` in your home directory on both systems. Your system might have the initial version of some missing files in `/etc/skel`. These files will be copied to the home directory when creating a new user.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want all your hosts to have a prompt of the form `user@host$`, you need to add to your [`$HOME/.bashrc`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) on each of these machines the correct value of [`PS1`](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/bash-shell-ps1-10-examples-to-make-your-linux-prompt-like-angelina-jolie/):

```
PS1='\u@\h$ '
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have deleted the .bashrc file

```
vi .bashrc
```

put this code

```
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

now `su root`